# What does "sécher mes colles" mean?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

I listened to a song of Francis Lemarque and there was a phrase in it which I could not understand.

Here is the verse:

> A côté du canal
> Y'a l'école communale
> Où j'ai vécu ma vie
> Tout p'tit
> L'canal n'a pas bougé
> Mais l'école a changé
> On a remis d'la peinture sur
> Les murs
> Un nouveau personnel
> D'autres instituteurs
> Et un vieux Directeur
> Solennel
> M'ont rappelé le temps
> **Où je séchais mes colles**
> Sur les bancs de l'école
> En pleurant
> M'ont rappelé le temps
> Où je séchais mes colles
> Sur les bancs de l'école
> En pleurant

Could you please tell me what it means? Is it sort of fixed expression or slang?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Colle' is detention (you can also say 'Retenue') and 'sécher les cours' means 'to skip class', so according to me 'je séchais mes colles' means 'I skipped detention'.

<strike>But then why 'Sur les bancs de l'école'? I'm sure there are much more pleasant places to skip detention.</strike>

Edit: removed that line after @LukeSawczak's comment.

Comment: Perhaps the colles, not the place he went to skip them, were on the bancs :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Good point, thanks, it looks obvious now after your comment

Comment: These are lyrics written by a poet. So let us not forget the necessity of rimes, poetic licence and so forth. So why wouldn't *colle* take both meanings? What I mean is that poetry lets a certain freedom of interpretation to the reader.

Comment: "skipped detention "en pleurant"?

Comment: While skipping detention is the most natural meaning in the context of primary school, I don't understand how it fits the sentence. If you're skipping, then you aren't “sur les bancs de l'école”.

Comment: @Gilles Luke already provided a very plausible explanation: *c'est les colles qui avaient lieu sur les bancs de l'école mais lui, il les séchait.*

Comment: But, still, @LPH's point is valid: why would you cry when skipping detention? Or is it the remembrance of those days that makes him cry?

Comment: The second alternative,, tears of emotion.

Comment: Guys, I am sorry that I am late for your discussion. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Dear @jlliagre, I really could not understand how _Où je séchais mes colles_ and _Sur les bancs de l'école_ were connected to each other. They were actually not, haha. Thank you for your explanation, for "tears of emotion"!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, if this verb is used with un object it means "to skip (school, classes,…)"; its register is school slang.

> ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s%C3%A9cher/71717)
> Familier. Manquer volontairement un cours, une réunion, etc.
> ♦  Sécher le lycée

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9cher)) **B.** − Empl. arg.
> **1.** Arg. scol.
> a) […]
> **b)** Manquer volontairement (un cours, l'école).
> ♦ Mon cher commandant (...) me dit le curé, avec la bille têtue et pas d'accord des mômes résolus à sécher la classe, c'est en ce lieu démantelé que vous envisagez mon entretien avec le colonel Moscardo?

Another use of the verb "sécher" is as follows; it is not used with an object (intransitive) or the preposition "sur" or "en" is necessary; in this case it means "to be stumped".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9cher)) B. − Empl. arg. Sécher (sur qqc.). Être incapable de répondre, d'argumenter sur un sujet (notamment lors d'une interrogation scolaire). Synon. rester sec*.Afin de lui faire « acquérir une personnalité », il la laissait une heure durant, le sang aux joues, à sécher sur une lettre à un vieil oncle ou à son parrain: elle avait consigne d'écrire une lettre « originale » (Montherl.,Pitié femmes, 1936, p. 1083).

- Les élèves séchaient souvent en chimie.
- Il a séché sur l'épreuve de mathématiques.

There is the possibility that "colle" does not mean "very difficult question" or "sticky question" but instead "mock oral exam" (examen blanc); however, this is not  possibility because when he does that he is in school (sur les bancs de l'école). It appears then that this is a new or rare usage (perhaps due to poetic license): instead of saying "je séchais **sur** mes colles" (I was stumped on the sticky questions given to me"), the transitive form "je séchais mes colles" is used to mean the same thing.

Comment: I have great difficulty following your reasoning. What is this "new hybrid usage" you are referring to? Let us not forget that this song was written and first published in 1958, so new in relation to what? Then, to my knowledge *séchais sur* has never meant, neither fifty years ago nor now,  the same as *séchais*  used transitively.

Comment: [...] Saying that *colle* here doesn't have the meaning of *examen blanc* is not entirely wrong but not quite right either, this way of explaining it could be misleading.  *Examen blanc*  takes place in the same conditions (timing, content, marking...) as the proper exam it is supposed to "mock"; whereas a *colle*, which belongs to the *argot préparationnaire* is a specific oral exercise which usually lasts an hour.

Comment: @None It would be new (perhaps even the result of poetic license) because the only recorded usage (that I could find) entails the use of a preposition; I never heard it used differently myself. Since "mes colles" is apparently taken as meaning "what in some subjects  were sticky questions for me", it follows that the transitive verb "to skip" becomes the intransitive "to be at a loss"; however, I think you are right, "hybrid" is not the proper word because there is **not** one part of one meaning and a part of the other in the final term; so I'll change that.

Comment: “Colle” can mean an oral exam (not just a mock one), but this is slang which is only used in the specific context of *grandes écoles* (certain kinds of post-secondary education), not in the context of primary school. “Colle” can mean a trick question (a stumper), and this is everyday vocabulary (not very common, but not specific to a particular demographic), but this unlikely to happen at the primary school level. Both “je séchais sur mes colles” and “the séchais mes colles” are weird phrasings but neither of them feels outright wrong to me, especially in a song with meter constraints. @None

Answer (score 1):

J'ai lu avec intérêt les autres réponses et les commentaires. Je ne connais pas l'auteur mais on sait qu'il a quitté l'école à 11 ans après avoir obtenu un certificat d'études primaires ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Lemarque#Origines_familiales_et_jeunesse), [Maitron](https://maitron.fr/spip.php?article73694)).

Au sujet du verbe *sécher*, le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sup. Rey, chez Robert) traite de son emploi en argot scolaire du 19<sup>e</sup> pour « mal noter (un candidat) de manière à le recaler », qui serait sorti d'usage et clairement ce n'est pas le narrateur qui note ici. Puis on a « être embarrassé pour répondre » qu'on dit en relation avec une acception de *sec* et de *sèche*, le déverbal de *sécher* dans le sens de « ne pas répondre » (comme dans *piquer une sèche*) et on fait le lien avec *rester sec* en ne répondant pas à une interrogation. Évidemment [*sécher ses cours*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/46604) (ne pas y assister) est aussi usuel comme sens que comme réalité...

Mais sécher ses *colles* ? Le DHLF nous dit que l'argot scolaire du 20<sup>e</sup> donne 3 sens au mot *colle* : *exercice d'interrogation, question embarrassante* puis, un peu plus tard, *punition retenue*.

---

Il me semble plutôt naturel de relier *être embarrassé pour répondre/ne pas répondre* et *exercice d'interrogation/question embarrassante* et l'absence de [préposition](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/46605) entre *sécher* et *colles* ne m'inquiète pas ; s'agit-il d'une ellipse de celle-ci ou est-ce basé sur le prototype plus usuel avec *cours*, qu'importe !

> [Ces lieux et ces gens] m'ont rappelé <strike>en pleurant</strike> le temps où je séchais mes
> colles sur les bancs de l'école en pleurant.

On peut se souvenir de quelque chose *en pleurant* mais ici ce seraient les lieux et les gens qui me rappellent quelque chose en pleurant ? Par ailleurs pourquoi la visite d'une école qu'on a fréquentée nous rappellerait des souvenirs de ne pas y être ? Et pourquoi pleurerait-on ? De joie ? Finalement, est-il vraiment réaliste qu'on permette à un élève de la petite école de ne pas assister à une retenue (qui est déjà une punition pour une autre raison), et ce, à répétition, voire même une seule fois ? Je trouve une telle chose inconcevable.

---

Il peut y avoir double sens, et c'est peut-être ça le génie du texte, mais seule une interprétation comme « être embarrassé pour répondre à une interrogation » permet, il me semble, de donner effet à tous les mots du texte et d'en assurer sa cohérence. La chanson évoquerait dans ce cas le souvenir de l'humiliation.